# Label vertical axis in BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: graphics, labeling

I would like to label the units of the vertical axis on a BoxWhiskerChart, but haven't figured out how to do so. I tried `AxesLabel` and I tried giving the data units, but neither worked for me in version 11.1.1

```
BoxWhiskerChart[Quantity[RandomReal[{0, 10}, {100}], "USDollars"], 
 AxesLabel -> {"Test"}]
```

[image: BoxWhiskerChart]

How can I label the vertical axis?

Comment: You must use `FrameLabel -> {"", "Test"}, RotateLabel -> False`, as you have a `Frame` not axes.

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Thank you! If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I you want to see the units as a label, you could use FrameLabel->Automatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `FrameLabel->{"", "Test"}, RotateLabel -> False`, therefore:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[Quantity[RandomReal[{0, 10}, {100}], "USDollars"], 
FrameLabel -> {"", "Test"}, RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
Labeled[BoxWhiskerChart[Quantity[RandomReal[{0, 10}, {100}], "USDollars"]], 
  Style["Test", 12, "Panel"], Left, RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]

```
Panel[BoxWhiskerChart[Quantity[RandomReal[{0, 10}, {100}], "USDollars"]], 
 "Test", Left, RotateLabel -> True, Appearance -> "Frameless"]
```

[image]